# Add Check Constraint On Varchar Column to enforce no duplicates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a `varchar(max)` column where users will populate a pre-given key from another system. I want to enable that the users are forced to enter a unique key which means no duplicate values on that specific column. Should I change the collation or is there some sort of check constraint that I can add?

Comment: People are entering > 900 bytes by hand? This does not sound like a "key" to me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ordinarily, you'd just create a [unique constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177420%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on that column. But you can't put a unique constraint on a varchar(max) column. That could be close to 2GB per index entry.

In SQL Server, the [maximum size of an index key is 900 bytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx). I believe SQL Server enforces unique constraints by using a unique index, so I'd expect that limitation to apply to your problem, too.

In any case, I think this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I don't think you can have a unique constraint on a `varchar(max)`. It's up to `VARCHAR(8000)`.

Comment: @ypercube: Yeah, I realized it was a varchar(max) column right after I posted, and I was looking for the limits. Thanks.

Comment: Values have changed in newer versions: "The maximum allowable size of the combined index values is 900 bytes for a clustered index, or 1,700 for a nonclustered index. The limits are 16 columns and 900 bytes for versions before SQL Database and SQL Server 2016 (13.x)."